# Selectively applying example weights

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a weighted dataset, and a model composed of two parts.

How can I train the model in such a way that the dataset weights only apply to the first part of it (while the second part is trained as if each example had the same weight)?

Comment: what are the model parts'? are they two input/output branches? could u please provide some details about this model

Comment: One part is a subnetwork whose output feeds into the main network.

Comment: The main network is the one to which the weights should apply.

Comment: Can you give a more specific question relating to your tags? Right now this seems less like a TensorFlow question and more like a question for a different StackExchange.

Comment: As far as the tensorflow part, you'll need to freeze the model weights that are not affected by one loss. Then unfreeze them if you have a second loss. See [TensorFlow docs on freezing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#freeze_the_convolutional_base).

Comment: I want to achieve this in Tensorflow, hence the tag. I only have one loss function.

Comment: As long as two networks are of same architecture, you can share the weights between them. Save the checkpoints of first network and load it evaluate the main network. To know more about the tensorflow library to save the checkpoints and load find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training). Thanks